# WEB API ODATA error "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request"

Tags: odata, wcf-data-services, asp.net-web-api

I am using WEB API ODATA with Telerik OpenAccess

Here is OpenAccessBaseApiController.cs

```
public abstract partial class OpenAccessBaseApiController<TEntity, TContext> : ODataController
    where TContext : OpenAccessContext, new()
{
    protected IOpenAccessBaseRepository<TEntity, TContext> repository;

    public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> Get()
    {
        var allEntities = repository.GetAll();
        return allEntities;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new entity based on the provided data
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="entity">The new entity to be created</param>
    /// <returns>HTTP Status:
    /// - Accepted when operation is successful or 
    /// - MethodNotAllowed if the operation is disabled for this entity or
    /// - BadRequest if the provided entity is NULL</returns>
    public virtual HttpResponseMessage Post(TEntity entity)
    {
        if (entity == null)
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

        //TODO: should we check if the incomming entity is not an existing one?
        TEntity newEntity = repository.AddNew(entity);

        var response = CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Accepted, newEntity);
        return response;
    }

    protected abstract HttpResponseMessage CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode httpStatusCode, TEntity entityToEmbed);
}
```

Here is default NumberSequencesController.cs

```
public partial class NumberSequencesController : OpenAccessBaseApiController<MyERP.DataAccess.NumberSequence, MyERP.DataAccess.EntitiesModel>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor used by the Web API infrastructure.
    /// </summary>
    public NumberSequencesController()
    {
        this.repository = new NumberSequenceRepository();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Dependency Injection ready constructor.
    /// Usable also for unit testing.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>Web API Infrastructure will ALWAYS use the default constructor!</remarks>
    /// <param name="repository">Repository instance of the specific type</param>
    public NumberSequencesController(IOpenAccessBaseRepository<MyERP.DataAccess.NumberSequence , MyERP.DataAccess.EntitiesModel> repository)
    {
        this.repository = repository;
    }
...
}
```

Here is my implement NumberSequencesController.partial.cs

```
    public partial class NumberSequencesController 
{
    public SingleResult<NumberSequence> GetNumberSequence([FromODataUri] Guid key)
    {
        return SingleResult.Create(repository.GetAll().Where(c => c.Id == key).AsQueryable());
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Updates single entity.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>Replaces the whole existing entity with the provided one</remarks>
    /// <param name="id">ID of the entity to update</param>
    /// <param name="entity">Entity with the new updated values</param>
    /// <returns>HttpStatusCode.BadRequest if ID parameter does not match the ID value of the entity,
    /// or HttpStatusCode.NoContent if the operation was successful</returns>
    public HttpResponseMessage PutNumberSequence([FromODataUri] Guid id, MyERP.DataAccess.NumberSequence entity)
    {
        if (entity == null || id != entity.Id)
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

        repository.Update(entity);

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
    }
}
```

My ODATA url :

```
http://localhost//MyERP.Web/odata/NumberSequences(guid'f640510c-365e-434f-9377-0118f22319fc')
```

work well. But when i PUT update ODATA i have error No HTTP resource was found that matches the request. Here is Fidder data

```
PUT /MyERP.Web/odata/NumberSequences(guid'f640510c-365e-434f-9377-0118f22319fc') 

HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 1855
Cache-Control: no-cache
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.114 Safari/537.36
Origin: chrome-extension://fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm
Authorization: Basic REVNTzpXQVpOODFQQy9RY0NsMmRDc01ZZGp3PT0=
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,vi;q=0.6
```

BODY

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" 
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" 
xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
  <id>http://localhost/MyERP.Web/odata/NumberSequences(guid'f640510c-365e-434f-9377-0118f22319fc')</id>
  <category term="MyERP.DataAccess.NumberSequence" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
  <title />
  <updated>2014-05-28T07:50:39Z</updated>
  <author><name /></author>
  <content type="application/xml">
    <m:properties>
      <d:ClientId m:type="Edm.Guid">28cc612c-807d-458d-91e7-f759080b0e40</d:ClientId>
      <d:Code>GL002</d:Code>
      <d:CurrentNo m:type="Edm.Int32">1</d:CurrentNo>
      <d:EndingNo m:type="Edm.Int32">9999</d:EndingNo>
      <d:FormatNo>GL000</d:FormatNo>
      <d:Id m:type="Edm.Guid">f640510c-365e-434f-9377-0118f22319fc</d:Id>
      <d:IsDefault m:type="Edm.Boolean">false</d:IsDefault>
      <d:Manual m:type="Edm.Boolean">false</d:Manual>
      <d:Name>Chung tu tong hop</d:Name>
      <d:NoSeqName>seq_no_series_f640510c_365e_434f_9377_0118f22319fc</d:NoSeqName>
      <d:OrganizationId m:type="Edm.Guid">4336fecf-8c21-4531-afe6-76d34603ea34</d:OrganizationId>
      <d:RecCreated m:type="Edm.DateTime">2014-05-11T00:28:57.754334</d:RecCreated>
      <d:RecCreatedBy m:type="Edm.Guid">5e6af2aa-e21a-4afd-815e-0cc3dbefa08a</d:RecCreatedBy>
      <d:RecModified m:type="Edm.DateTime">2014-05-11T00:28:57.754334</d:RecModified>
      <d:RecModifiedBy m:type="Edm.Guid">5e6af2aa-e21a-4afd-815e-0cc3dbefa08a</d:RecModifiedBy>
      <d:StartingNo m:type="Edm.Int32">1</d:StartingNo>
      <d:Status m:type="Edm.Int16">1</d:Status>
      <d:StatusType>Active</d:StatusType>
      <d:Version m:type="Edm.Int64">1</d:Version>
    </m:properties>
  </content>
```

It have error :

```
    {
  "odata.error":{
    "code":"","message":{
      "lang":"en-US","value":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost/MyERP.Web/odata/NumberSequences(guid'f640510c-365e-434f-9377-0118f22319fc')'."
    },"innererror":{
      "message":"No action was found on the controller 'NumberSequences' that matches the request.","type":"","stacktrace":""
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please rename the "id" parameter of PutNumberSequence to "key".

From

```
public HttpResponseMessage PutNumberSequence(
    [FromODataUri] Guid id, MyERP.DataAccess.NumberSequence entity)
```

To

```
public HttpResponseMessage PutNumberSequence(
    [FromODataUri] Guid key, MyERP.DataAccess.NumberSequence entity)
```